# Awkward results from sklearn.metrics

Tags: scikit-learn, scikits

When doing `decisiontree` regression using default parameters, I got R2 value "**-1.3**". What does it means, is my model OK? The mean square error is also NOT reasonable. Can I make it positive by changing the parameters of the classifiers.

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.r2_score.html

```
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score, mean_squared_error
```

Answer (score 0):

A negative R2 is indicative of over-fitting, which is pretty typical for an untuned Decision tree fit to small or noisy training data.

You could address this by tuning the parameters of the Decision tree using, e.g. a [grid search](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html) – setting `max_depth` to a smaller value will probably cause the model to perform better in your case.

An even better approach would be to change to a [Random Forest](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#random-forests) model, which uses ensembles of decision trees to more automatically correct for such over-fitting (though tuning via grid search is still important to further optimize the results).